# complex queries in objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

Consider a more complex entity structure like

```
class Entity {
    Float valueA;
    Float valueB;
    List<Property> properties;
}

class Property {
    Long id;
    Float value;
}
```

I'm now trying to figure out an index structure to do queries like (Pseudo sql):

```
select entity where valueA >= x and valueB < y and properties contains
((id = a, value >= b) and (id = c, value = d))
```

The problems I'm facing are:

- I can't put multible inequality filters in one query.
- How would I add constraints for the list property objects

So far I have one idea that came accross my mind:

I could make use of the relation index pattern for all properties. Eg. create the following entities:

```
class ValueA/ValueB {
   @Parent
   Key<Entity> parent;
   @Id
   Long id = 1L;
   @Index
   Float minValue;
}
```

and change the Property class like

```
class Property {
    @Parent
    Key<Entity> parent;
    @Id
    Long id;
    @Index
    Float value;
}
```

Then I could do a query for every related index class and keep the parent keys of those entities that mach all criteria.

This would be hard to do efficiently and could easily get very expensive.

Are there any other solutions I could try out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For complex queries like this you may better off either denormalising your data model, or having a denormalised copy of the properties you want to filter on.  That said, it also depends what dataset and result set sizes you're looking at.  For example, with small result sets, maybe you can do a simpler query and then do further filtering within your application?

Comment: well, the balance between in app data processing and db filtering is not really the scope of my question. but lets say the data set could be big and I would like to do as much db filtering as possible.
I'm not quite shure how I would denormalize the entities in a good manner to fit the above query. Especially if there are more list properties.

Answer (score 1):

I would store a denormalized copy of my Entity in the Search Api, which allows for much more flexible querying.

Make sure that your result from the Search Api contains the Id of the entities.

Finally, do a keys() query with Objectify to get to the actual entities of your result.

Comment: definitely an idea worth spending time on!